# How to return the parent and its children without omitting the parent?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm not super experienced with SQL, so this maybe be a pretty easy solution. But, I'm having a lot of trouble with it. I can't come up with a perfectly analogous real-world situation, so I will just explain it verbatim.

I have a table(CGI_SUB) that has 2 columns: SUB and CGI. For ease of description lets give the table alias "a". There is no unique key in this table. Every CGI entry("parent) has a corresponding SUB entry. It's close to saying CGI = Parent and SUB is child from a relationship perspective; however, each parent will ALSO have the same SUB.

What I'm trying to do is output all the CGIs(including the "parent") IF it has children(2 or more SUBs in total). In essence, outputting parents and their children only if they have children.

Table looks like this

```
| SUB | CGI  |
______________
| TTA | TTA  |
| NSN | NSN  |
| INF | NSN  |
| VWA | VWA  |
| POR | VWA  |
| BMW | BMW  |
```

You can see that in this case, NSN and VWA have "children" and TTA and BMW do not. So, I would want to output NSN, VWA, and their children:

```
| SUB |
_______
| NSN |
| INF |
| VWA |
| POR |
```

Thanks for any help!

Craig

EDITED: spelling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select a.sub from x a inner join x b  where (a.sub<>b.sub and a.cpi=b.cpi);

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two levels then a hierarchical approach would probably be overkill; so one approach is to use an `exists` clause to check for a non-matching parent/child record:

```
select a.sub
from cgi_sub a
where exists (
  select null from cgi_sub b where b.cgi = a.cgi and b.sub != b.cgi
);
```

That will exclude any rows where there isn't (also) a row for that `cgi` which has a non-matching `sub`.

With your sample as a CTE:

```
with cgi_sub (sub, cgi) as (
  select 'TTA', 'TTA' from dual
  union all select 'NSN', 'NSN' from dual
  union all select 'INF', 'NSN' from dual
  union all select 'VWA', 'VWA' from dual
  union all select 'POR', 'VWA' from dual
  union all select 'BMW', 'BMW' from dual
)
select a.sub
from cgi_sub a
where exists (
  select null from cgi_sub b where b.cgi = a.cgi and b.sub != b.cgi
);

SUB
---
INF
NSN
POR
VWA
```

Answer (score 0):

@Vani 's response put me on the right track.
Here's what I wound up with that worked

```
  Select Distinct(a.sub) FROM CGI_SUB a
  INNER JOIN CGI_SUB b
    ON b.cgi = a.cgi
  WHERE (a.sub <> b.sub AND a.CGI = b.CGI)
```